# Xcode - Saving button click sequence and replaying the actions in saved order?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, uibutton, selector

I am trying to save the order in which the buttons are pressed, and then replay that order and run the actions assigned to the buttons in the order they were originally pressed? Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Didnt get the question. could you explain?

Comment: Basically i want the user to press a variety of buttons, each button has its own action assigned to it.  it runs the actions as each button is pressed and also saves the order that they were pressed so when the user selects a play button, it will run through the actions in the order the pressed the buttons first time around...does this make sense? thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `UIControl` element has a tag which you can use to be able to identify between the various buttons that are going to be tapped. As each button is tapped, the method (selector) associated with that button will be called (you can even have a single selector be called for all the buttons and differentiate between them via their tags).

As each button is tapped, keep track of which button is tapped by adding the tag of each button to a queue (or in Objective-C: `NSMutableArray`). Then to replay the actions you can merely read the tag values from the queue and call the corresponding selector.

An example to illustrate:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *taskArray;

// in your init or viewDidLoad:
_taskArray = [NSMutableArray new];

// in the selector that is called by *all* buttons
-(IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    [_taskArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]];
    [self executeActionWithTag:sender.tag];
}

-(void) executeActionWithTag:(NSUInteger)tag {
    if(tag == 1) {
         // perform specific action 1 ...
    } else if (tag == 2) {
         // perform specific action 2 ...
    } 
    // ...
}

-(void) replayButtonActions {
    for (NSNumber *tag in _taskArray) {
        [self executeActionWithTag:[tag integerValue]];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i know how to assign the method to each button tag.  Not sure how i would write the code to save to NSMutableArray, would this use NSUserDefaults? And how i would then replay the actions in the order they was saved?

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example of how you might do this within a single app session only. If you want to persist the actions across app sessions so that even when the user closes the app and comes back the actions are remembered, yes you would want to use something like NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your help...I have managed to get the buttons tags to work, but when i replay the action it only plays the last button pressed, doesn't seem to store more than one?

Comment: I would recommend you make a new question with the new problem you are having and include the relevant code and link to it here so that I can check it out. If my answer answered your question (or got you on the right track) please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Right below the upvote/downvote arrows there is an outline of a checkmark. Merely click on the checkmark to make it solid green and the question will be marked as answered.